# Posting data by XMLHttpReques does not return json value

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-ajax

I post data by `XMLHttpRequest` to `controller`. I pass only `string` with value `"1"`. When I check request with fiddler everything is ok. There is `JSON` `rara=1`. Request connect to method in controller, but there `rara` is `null`.

Below code from js:

```
StopThreadHandlerBase.prototype.sendInterruption = function (number, path) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", path, false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) {
            var message = 'Thread Stopped';
            if (number === 3) {
                message = message + ', Asset sold';
            }

            if (number === 5) {
                message = message + ', Asset bought';
            }

            alert(message);
            window.location.href = "/WebApplication2/Home/NewOrder";
        }
        else {
            alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
        }
    };
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ rara: number }));
}
```

Code from controller:

```
public void InterruptFirstThreadFastConditionService(string rara)
{
  var interruptionType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EnumInterruption>(rara);
  _fastConditionServiceHelper.setStopFirstThread(interruptionType);
}
```

I mention that I tried with `HttpPost`, `HttpGet`, `AllowAnnonymous` tags, but it do not work. What is more, I tried the same in .net framework and it worked.
The same does not work in .net core.

Please look into picture. There is rara with value 1, but it is not binded to argument from method.

[image]

Comment: I don't know if asp is smart enough to automatically handle json like that, but `'Content-Type'` should have a capital `T`

Comment: @Taplar have not helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending an object from JavaScript so you should create a view model class on server side, something like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Rara { get; set; }
}
```

And you can use it in the controller like this:

```
public void InterruptFirstThreadFastConditionService([FromBody] MyViewModel model)
{
  var interruptionType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EnumInterruption>(model.Rara);
  _fastConditionServiceHelper.setStopFirstThread(interruptionType);
}
```

Comment: Did not help. I consider, maybe I miss something with my middleware in startup.cs? Is there sth that I should remember or some packages which I have not installed or some binding problems?

Comment: I used ApiController, so it was working for me, but probably you are using normal controllers. I added [FromBody] before the parameter, this should solve your problem, and should work now.